# Django filter object by ManyToMany and only return those ManyToMany relationships that match

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ....

class User(models.Model):
    .....
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    
    group = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group, through="UserGroup")
    

class Group(models.Model:
    ....


class UserGroup(models.Model):
    ......
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .....
```

I want to be able to return the Groups that contains a User with a certain category
which I can do with...

```
queryset = Group.objects.all()
category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)
queryset = queryset.filter(user__category_id=category_id)
```

But this still returns all the Users associated to that Group even if the User.category does not equal the given category_id.   How do I exclude those Users out related to the Group that only the Users with the correct category are returned?

so if there was
user1 & user2 which both have the category_id of 1 and user3 has category_id 2, the Group is returned with only user1 & user2's data from the Serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the use of prefetch_related & Prefetch() will handle this nicely....

```
queryset = Group.objects.all()
users = User.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
queryset.filter(user__category_id=category_id).prefetch_related(Prefetch('user_set', queryset=users))
```